# How to set backend to ‘gloo’ on windows in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, distributed, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use two gpus on my windows machine, but I keep getting

> raise RuntimeError("Distributed package doesn't have NCCL " "built
> in") RuntimeError: Distributed package doesn't have NCCL built in

I am still new to pytorch and couldnt really find a way of setting the backend to ‘gloo’. Any way to set backend= 'gloo' to run two gpus on windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
from torch import distributed as dist
```

Then in your init of the training logic:

```
dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
```

Update:

You should use python multiprocess like this:

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, rank, world_size):
        self.rank = rank
        self.world_size = world_size
        self.log('Initializing distributed')
        os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = self.args.distributed_addr
        os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = self.args.distributed_port
        dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    mp.spawn(
        Trainer,
        nprocs=world_size,
        args=(world_size,),
        join=True)
```

Comment: thx for the answer! If I am using two gpus, what would be rank and world_size?

Comment: if I put rank=[0,1] it gives me an error that it must be an integer

Comment: I am sorry that I wasnt clear in my question, but I am actually using pytorch-lightning, does your answer work in that case?

Comment: I didn't check it, but should work